# Pass load a .xib named in a plist when item selected in table

Tags: xcode, ios4, plist

Hi I'm trying to update an app I'm working on. Originally the app was a five view tab view app. I've decided that I want to modify the app so that it has less tabs and so I want to move three of the tabs into a table list and load them from there, thus freeing up some tab bar space for some other things I'd like to work on implementing.

TO achieve this I figured I'd set up a table view and load the details into the tableView from a .plist. I figured that I could name the .xib files in the .plist then grab these names and use them to push the appropriate .xib files into the view. It all sounds alright in theory (at least in my head) but I'm having some problems doing this. I can make the .plist work fine in terms of creating the table view but I'm coming unstuck because I don't know how to pass the name of the nib in and use it to push the correct view. Can anyone explain this to me. My plist looks like this:

```
<array>
<dict>
    <key>rowData</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>calcType</key>
            <string>Item 1</string>
            <key>subdetails</key>
            <string>some stuff about item 1</string>
            <key>nibName</key>
            <string>nibOne.xib</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>calcType</key>
            <string>Item 2</string>
            <key>subdetails</key>
            <string>some stuff about item 2</string>
            <key>nibName</key>
            <string>nibTwo.xib</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>calcType</key>
            <string>Item 3</string>
            <key>subdetails</key>
            <string>some stuff about item 3</string>
            <key>nibName</key>
            <string>nibThree.xib</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

my didSelectRowAtIndex method currently looks like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


     //Get the dictionary of the selected data source.
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[[self.artCalculators     objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"rowData"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

CalcDetailViewController *controller = [[CalcDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CalcDetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 

 controller.title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"calcType"];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

I know the line that needs changing is:

```
CalcDetailViewController *controller = [[CalcDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CalcDetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

But I'm not really sure what it need to be. Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the nib name out of the dictionary the same way you get any other object out of the dictionary:

```
NSString *nibName = [dictionary objectForKey:@"nibName"];
CalcDetailViewController *controller = [[CalcDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
```

You don't need to explicitly pass in the main bundle, this is the default if you pass in `nil`.

Comment: Thanks Jim, Though with adding this it's now crashing. I've used NSLog to check and it's grabbing the name of the .xib from the .plist but it's then crashing with the message: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle...